# Which R package do I need to install to fix Error: could not find function geom_sf

Tags: r, installation, package

Trying to plot a vector file, packages installed `tidyverse, ggplot2`

```
ggplot() +  geom_sf(data = aoi_boundary_HARV, size = 3, color = "black", fill = "cyan1") + ggtitle("AOI Boundary Plot") +  coord_sf()
```

> Error: could not find function geom_sf

yes sf package was installed same problems

2.2.1
do that means my r studio is an old version and should install the most recent one or something else

I had to do installr for an update

now
%>%
and error message
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialLinesDataFrame', 'SpatialLines', 'Spatial', 'SpatialLinesNULL')"

Comment: Did you install and load `sf`? It isn't part of the official `tidyverse`, I believe. Try `install.packages("sf")`

Comment: What version of the ggplot2 library are you using?  (check with `packageVersion('ggplot2')`.)  `geom_sf` was added in 3.0.

Comment: If 2.2.1 is your `ggplot2` version number, then you need to update that package. You may need to restart R to do it, and then run `install.packages('ggplot2')` to get the current version.